# Reseting timer automatically in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I have a problem with restarting timer in react.js. What I want to achieve is: when the timer reaches certain value (f.ex 20 as in my example) it restarts to 0 and automatically continues, without any event, counting again automatically.

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

require('../../sass/main.scss');

class TypeAnimation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sec: 0,

        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                sec: this.state.sec + 1
            });
        }, 100);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.sec === 20) {
              clearInterval(this.textInterval);
              this.firstTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    sec: 0
                });
              }, 3000);
          }
        }

    render() {
        const inText = this.props.text[0];
        const firstLine = inText.substr(0, this.state.sec);


        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    {firstLine}
                    <span className='blinker'> | </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TypeAnimation;
```

Comment: Move your logic from `componentDidUpdate` to your `setInterval`.

Comment: Side note: Your call to `setState` in that `componentDidMount` interval callback is wrong; [details](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). **Never** create a new state object based on `this.state`. Always use the callback version of `setState` and the argument it passes you.

Comment: Try not to mix es2015 imports and commonjs syntax. In other words, you may replace your `require('../../sass/main.scss');` with `import '../../sass/main.scss';` without any problems. The latest webpack supports this without any transpilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the state in the timer, or if you want to wait for `componentDidUpdate`, start a new timer each time from there. But regardless, be sure **not** to pass an object based on current state into `setState`, that's a mistake; [details](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Instead, use the callback version:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({sec: (prevState.sec + 1) % 20})); // % 20 resets to 0 at 20
```

Here we do all the updates in the timer (no `componentDidUpdate`):

```js
class TypeAnimation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sec: 0,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
            // Note use of the callback version, it matters
            this.setState(prevState => ({sec: (prevState.sec + 1) % 20})); // % 20 resets to 0 at 20
        }, 100);
    }

    render() {
        const inText = this.props.text[0];
        const firstLine = inText.substr(0, this.state.sec);

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    {firstLine}
                    <span className='blinker'> | </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TypeAnimation text={["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Here we want for `componentDidUpdate` before scheduling the next update (e.g., `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`):

```js
class TypeAnimation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sec: 0,
        };
    }

    scheduleUpdate() {
        if (this.textTimer) {
            clearTimeout(this.textTimer);
        }
        this.textTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            // Note use of the callback version, it matters
            this.setState(prevState => ({sec: (prevState.sec + 1) % 20})); // % 20 resets to 0 at 20
            this.textTimer = 0;
        }, 100);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.scheduleUpdate();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.scheduleUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        const inText = this.props.text[0];
        const firstLine = inText.substr(0, this.state.sec);

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    {firstLine}
                    <span className='blinker'> | </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TypeAnimation text={["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
       sec: prevState.sec < 20 ? prevState.sec + 1 : 0
    }));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is updating every 100ms it should be 1000

Answer (score 1):

P.S make sure to clear interval on componentWillUnmount life cycle.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState, currentProps) => {
        return {sec: prevState.sec !== 20 ? prevState.sec+1 : 0};
      });
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer sir, with the prevState approach. Is this correct approach?